# Why does table-create fail when everything's innodb, but not when one table is MyIsam?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, mysql-error-1005

I find innodb quite annoying when I try to design a db structure, at least compared with MyIsam, which seems to have less limitations

Say, if I want to create a simple library system.
And I have four tables.

1,table `book_item`, which records the book_name, author, publish time and those basic information about books

2, table `book`, which represents a specific real object of the book item. So a book_item object can relate to many book objects.

3, table `tag`, which represents a book tag. Like science, literature, architecture and so on.

4, table `tag_book_item_relation`, which relates tags to book_items.

So, the relations are as below.

1,we have a **book item** to **book** is **one-to-many** relationship

2,**book_item** to **tag** is **many-to-many** relationship.

Note here, engine for the table are all **innodb**
If I try to create the tables, it will fail:

```
Error:
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'yet_another_test.book' (errno: 121)
```

However, if I change the engine of `book` or `tag_book_item_relation` to **MyISAM**, everything will be fine.

So, I am wondering what is going wrong if I use engine **innodb** for  table`book` and `tag_book_item_relation`

The sql script is here(forward engineering in MySQL workbench):

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yet_another_test`.`tag` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yet_another_test`.`book_item` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yet_another_test`.`tag_book_item_relation` (
  `book_item_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `tag_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_item_id`, `tag_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_tag` (`tag_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_book_item` (`book_item_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tag`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id` )
    REFERENCES `yet_another_test`.`tag` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_item`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_item_id` )
    REFERENCES `yet_another_test`.`book_item` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yet_another_test`.`book` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `book_item_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `book_item_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_book_item` (`book_item_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_item`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_item_id` )
    REFERENCES `yet_another_test`.`book_item` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: The primary key is already unique, so there's no need to add a unique index in `tag` and `book_item`.

Comment: Huh?  InnoDB is awesome, MyISAM is the devil.  Why a database engine that does not understand the concept of a transaction is even supported, let alone used by default, by MySQL is beyond me.  A non-transactional database is a toy, at best.

Comment: I do agree InnoDb performs better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your tables without the `Foreign Key` constraints. Although the same statements work with MyISAM engine, the constraints are silently ignored there - that is why you are not getting the errors. If you really need those constraints, then create them correctly. However, I generally tend to avoid FK constraints and implement the constraints at application level.

One problem I spot right away are the symbols of your constraints which have to be unique at DB level and you have `fk_book_item` both on `tag_book_item_relation` table and on `book` table

Comment: Suggesting not to use FK is questionable at best http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616578/foreign-keys-when-cascades-arent-needed

Comment: I'm a little paranoid - I like to do everything explicitly - when I delete an `orders` record, I don't want my `order-lines` to be deleted, unless I delete them explicitly. Yes, I might get orphan records in DB, but usually that is what I want. I think it's a matter of preferences here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an issue with the "CREATE TABLE `book`" that the foreign key constraint `fk_book_item` has the same name as the constraint in `tag_book_item_relation`. Try using another name for the constraint in `book` and the CREATE TABLE should work fine.

This isn't a problem in MyISAM because they have no concept of foreign-keys and so the FK constraints are ignored.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

ERROR 121 says "Table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table."

[Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html)

The Index Name and Constraint Name may be same, change that try creating the table.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is saying that there is a duplicate key somewhere. It can be caused by a name conflict in a foreign key constraint; you cannot use the same foreign key name in different tables. (I don't know what other tables might be in your data base.)

Often, the error is caused by the table already existing in InnoDB's internal dictionary, even though the .frm file is gone. If that's the case, then the easiest thing to do is to do an sql dump of the data, drop the data base, recreate it, and then load the data from the dump.